# Hard drive bad - Failed clone

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, mbr, gpt, hard-drive-recovery

I have a harddisk that was failing. I wanted to clone the disk to an other hard disk, but the program needed the disk to be a mbr disk instead of a gpt disk. So I transformed it to a mbr disk, but now the data is unreadable. I forgot that the disk is 3TB and mbr only supports disk to 2TB. The disk doesn't has any partitions any more now. So I tried setting it to gpt again, but that didn't work. The program I used for this is Acronis Disk Director.

Is there a way to recover the files? I guess the bits aren't overwritten yet, so it should be salvageable like deleted files are. I tried EaseUS Partition Recovery Wizard, but it couldn't use a gpt disk.

What's the best way to approach this? I got most files on a backup, but not all, so I want to try to get those back.

Comment: Welcome to SU! How did you "transform" the drive to MBR without formatting it?

Comment: Acronis Disk Director has an option to change from mbr to gpt (and back) without formatting the whole drive.

Comment: So why can't you use use Acronis to make it gpt again?

Comment: I did that, but now my data isn't accessible anymore, so now I want to see if I can get my data back like you would with a deleted file

Comment: Based on what you discribe file recover at this point is unlikely.

Comment: If originally it was NTFS, then data recovery is very likely. ;)

Comment: Yes it was NTFS. There should be a way to recover some files? I always read that when you delete a file, it isn't deleted. Only in the index the file is deleted so the bits of the file can be overwritten. There has to be some tool I can use to scrape those files. The disk hasn't written anything after.

Comment: I have found a tool called PhotoRec. It can recover a lot of different type of deleted files looking at the fileheader. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec